# Component for large choice buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

What type of component is used in samsung s health main window for items (like in attached photo)? I want similar functionality. Main think is that i want to define N number of buttons. And then display it to users. Usually there will be 2 or 3 choises. So, what is best component for this task? I must add some text and maybe an picture.

[image: s health main window]

Comment: It could be ImageView or some composite, even a button with a background. You can actually set an OnClickListener on any view.

Comment: It's `RecylerView` with `GridLayout` so you can have N number of Items. It's up to you how you make each item. User CardView or Linear/Relative layout etc